# Windows10 System Restore point got deleted after failed restore attempt

Tags: windows, windows-10, restore, system-restore

OS: Windows 10 (I believe it's Educational version) 1903 - with all updates available.

Here's what happened:

1. I started System Restore to a point from few hours ago (installed an
   app that messed up my env vars - whatever...)
2. It all looked fine, PC rebooted and was chilling on black loading
   screen (with white circle spinning)
3. After a while I came back and PC was shut down. Strange.
4. Fired it up, got "CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED" BSOD.
5. Automatic repair couldn't fix it, so I went to Advanced > System
   Restore and chose an option to undo previous system restore.
6. Got an error "something about WindowsApps folder"
7. Launched System Restore again, undo option was missing so I chose
   the initial restore point
8. Got an error "something about unpacking contents"
9. Launched System Restore again, no restore points are available (it
   was the only one I created)

Current status:

- PC won't boot, in normal nor in safe mode - CRITICAL PROCESS DIED
  blue screen
- Automatic repair also from USB recovery won't work - logfile says it
  couldn't find a cause
- I can access CMD

I could try to figure out these errors but can't retry the restore anyway because it seems like Windows just deleted these points.

Does anyone have any idea what to try next?

Comment: I'd start with the "app that messed up my env vars" & wonder whether it wasn't actually malicious. if there's any slight chance it was, then nuke & pave then recover to last backup. Otherwise see if you can test the drive for errors, because it sounds like you're making things worse not better. If no backup, then consider data recovery before anything else.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not the case in this situation. Im sure it's 100% safe and didn't break anything else beside few env vars. Drive has no errors. "Recovering" isn't a problem either. I'll just go with full fresh install and restore from backup - few lost hours at max. Just wanted to find a solution why system restore didnt help and actually broke my PC (and then deleted restore points to cover its tracks) :D